# recursive clean in a Makefile

Tags: shell, recursion, makefile

I'm trying to create a Makefile which can build/clean recursively when it's called. I have the build working, but I'm getting errors with the clean command.

My directory structure is something like:

```
main
 |
 +-- Makefile
 |
 +-- common
 |      |
 |      +-- gcas_debug
 |      |      |
 |      |      +-- Makefile
 |      + -- gcas_nvdata
 |             |
 |             +-- Makefile
 +-- gcinit
        +-- Makefile
```

When I call `make` in the main directory it goes through and builds everything as I desire, but when I call `make clean` it does with:

```
mike@mike-VirtualBox:~/iCOM/framework$ make clean
for d in common/gcas_debug common/gcas_nvdata; \
    do \
    make --directory=$f clean; \
    done
make: the `-C' option requires a non-empty string argument
Usage: make [options] [target] ...
Options:
  -b, -m                      Ignored for compatibility.
...
```

I don't understand why the clean command isn't working... Any suggestions? 

Full (main) Makefile:

```
lib_gcas_debug := common/gcas_debug
lib_gcas_nvdata := common/gcas_nvdata
libraries := $(lib_gcas_debug) $(lib_gcas_nvdata)
DESTDIR=$(PWD)/output
bindir=

gc_init := gcinit
EXE := $(gc_init)/$(gc_init)

.PHONY: all $(gc_init) $(libraries)
all: $(gc_init)

$(gc_init) $(libraries):
    $(MAKE) --directory=$@

$(gc_init): $(libraries)

install: $(gc_init)
    install -d -m 0755 $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
    install -m 0755 $(EXE) $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)

clean:
    for d in $(libraries); \
    do \
    $(MAKE) --directory=$$f clean; \
    done
```

---

EDIT: If I swap the `for d` with `for $d` I get instead:

```
mike@mike-VirtualBox:~/iCOM/framework$ make clean
for  in common/gcas_debug common/gcas_nvdata; \
    do \
    make --directory= clean; \
    done
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `common/gcas_debug'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `for  in common/gcas_debug common/gcas_nvdata; \'
make: *** [clean] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the for loop again:

```
for d in [...]; do make --directory=$f
```

Didn't you mean `$d`, as in

```
for d in [...]; do make --directory=$d
```

So, the Makefile should look:

```
for d in common/gcas_debug common/gcas_nvdata; \
do \
    make --directory=$d clean; \
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'm not terribly familiar with Make/shell syntax so I was following "Managing Projects with GNU Make 3rd edition" and the syntax they used was just `d` not `$d`. When I do the swap as per your suggestion it now fails differently(See edit'ed question with the new error). So I suppose you're right about the `$d` as that looks better, but it seems it still doesn't "like" my `for` loop syntax.

Comment: @Mike: You don't replace the d in the for loop header, but the `$f` in the body. The loop variable is `$d`, not `$f`.

Comment: That was it, thank you! The book made some reference to `$$f` being a special argument for directories or files, so I got confused by that, but `$d` fixed it!

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
SUBDIRS := foo bar baz

.PHONY: subdirs $(SUBDIRS) clean all

subdirs: $(SUBDIRS) 

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)

clean: $(SUBDIRS)
    rm -rf dist

dist: $(SUBDIRS) dist/.build_marker

dist/.build_marker: 
    mkdir -p dist
    for d in $(SUBDIRS) ; do cp $$d/dist/* dist ; done
    touch dist/.build_marker
```

I only need to use the for loop in the *dist* target to copy files. This allows `make -j` build parallelism, not to mention simpler-to-read Makefiles.